# MSChart - Bar never passe the 100 when AxisY.Maximum > 100

Tags: .net, charts, mschart, asp.net-charts

I am using MSChart and I am trying to create a Bar chart. The AxisY.Maximum = 300, and I have multiple values passing the value 100. However for an unknown reason in the bar chart never passes the 100 points. It seems that somehow formats the value as if AxisY.Maximum = 100. Can someone explain to me what might be happening?

Exemple:
[image]

Comment: no code == no answer

Comment: Maybe you have set x-maximum to 17 ?